# Collection for Android Progressbar / Loading spinner

Tags: android

Does anyone know a collection for android progressbars / loading spinners.

There are some for web developers like [this](http://www.queness.com/post/9150/9-javascript-and-animated-gif-loading-animation-solutions) or generator like [this](http://heartcode.robertpataki.com/canvasloader/), or [spin.js](http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/) and so on...

I just googled a litte bit without success.

Is there a collection or generator for such spinners on android, with animations or somethings like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably the best resource for finding custom views and libraries: https://android-arsenal.com/tag/76

Not recommended, but you could use a GIF on Android or make it into an AnimationDrawable.